# how do you store a variable in an external file

Tags: python

So, i'm on assignment at school where i have create my own dice rolling game, i have completed everything but all i have to do now is store the scores that the user gets into a external file. I am new and have no idea how to do this, so could anybody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python program to store values in an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011077/python-program-to-store-values-in-an-external-file)

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - most importantly it's missing what you have tried yourself so far and where exactly you ran into a problem

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this kind of code.

```
        with open(file, "a") as f:
            f.write("write your content" + "\n")
```

But there are plenty of pages describing how to write content into files. Did you try these examples?

[Reading and writing files in Python.](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

Comment: You don't need to close the file manually. `with` does that for you.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.